# Spring Boot Quartz JDBC Jobstore with SQL Server database error

Tags: java, sql-server, spring-boot, jdbc, quartz-scheduler

I want to make a Quartz JDBC Jobstore in Spring Boot and connect it with my SQL Server database.If I run the project, I get this error:

> Failure obtaining db row lock: Zeile 1: Die FOR UPDATE-Klausel ist nur
> für DECLARE CURSOR zulässig.

This error only occurs as soon as I configure it with my SQL Server DB URL, with the H2 DB it works completely fine.

quartz.properties

```ini
#============================================================================
# Configure Main Scheduler Properties
#============================================================================
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName=spring-boot-quartz
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId=AUTO 

#============================================================================
# Configure ThreadPool
#============================================================================
org.quartz.threadPool.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 25
org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority = 5

#============================================================================
# Configure JobStore
#============================================================================
org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold=1000
org.quartz.jobStore.class=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.MSSQLDelegate
org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties=true
org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix=QRTZ_


#============================================================================
# Configure Cluster properties
#============================================================================
org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered=true
org.quartz.jobStore.clusterCheckinInterval=1000
```

application.properties

```ini
server.port=8080

spring.sql.init.schema-locations=classpath:db/quartz_tables_h2.sql
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://123.45.6.789;databaseName=myDB;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=debug

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
```

quartz_tables_h2.sql

```
USE myDB
GO

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.sysobjects WHERE id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[FK_QRTZ_TRIGGERS_QRTZ_JOB_DETAILS]') AND OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'ISFOREIGNKEY') = 1)
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[QRTZ_TRIGGERS] DROP CONSTRAINT FK_QRTZ_TRIGGERS_QRTZ_JOB_DETAILS
GO

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.sysobjects WHERE id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[FK_QRTZ_CRON_TRIGGERS_QRTZ_TRIGGERS]') AND OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'ISFOREIGNKEY') = 1)
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[QRTZ_CRON_TRIGGERS] DROP CONSTRAINT FK_QRTZ_CRON_TRIGGERS_QRTZ_TRIGGERS
GO

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.sysobjects WHERE id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[FK_QRTZ_SIMPLE_TRIGGERS_QRTZ_TRIGGERS]') AND OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'ISFOREIGNKEY') = 1)
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[QRTZ_SIMPLE_TRIGGERS] DROP CONSTRAINT FK_QRTZ_SIMPLE_TRIGGERS_QRTZ_TRIGGERS
GO

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.sysobjects WHERE id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[FK_QRTZ_SIMPROP_TRIGGERS_QRTZ_TRIGGERS]') AND OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'ISFOREIGNKEY') = 1)
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[QRTZ_SIMPROP_TRIGGERS] DROP CONSTRAINT FK_QRTZ_SIMPROP_TRIGGERS_QRTZ_TRIGGERS
GO

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.sysobjects WHERE id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[FK_QRTZ_BLOB_TRIGGERS_QRTZ_TRIGGERS]') AND OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'ISFOREIGNKEY') = 1)
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[QRTZ_BLOB_TRIGGERS] DROP CONSTRAINT FK_QRTZ_BLOB_TRIGGERS_QRTZ_TRIGGERS
GO

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.sysobjects WHERE id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[QRTZ_CALENDARS]') AND OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'ISUSERTABLE') = 1)
DROP TABLE [dbo].[QRTZ_CALENDARS]
GO

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.sysobjects WHERE id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[QRTZ_CRON_TRIGGERS]') AND OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'ISUSERTABLE') = 1)
DROP TABLE [dbo].[QRTZ_CRON_TRIGGERS]
GO

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.sysobjects WHERE id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[QRTZ_BLOB_TRIGGERS]') AND OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'ISUSERTABLE') = 1)
DROP TABLE [dbo].[QRTZ_BLOB_TRIGGERS]
GO

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.sysobjects WHERE id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[QRTZ_FIRED_TRIGGERS]') AND OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'ISUSERTABLE') = 1)
DROP TABLE [dbo].[QRTZ_FIRED_TRIGGERS]
GO

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.sysobjects WHERE id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[QRTZ_PAUSED_TRIGGER_GRPS]') AND OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'ISUSERTABLE') = 1)
DROP TABLE [dbo].[QRTZ_PAUSED_TRIGGER_GRPS]
GO

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.sysobjects WHERE id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[QRTZ_SCHEDULER_STATE]') AND OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'ISUSERTABLE') = 1)
DROP TABLE [dbo].[QRTZ_SCHEDULER_STATE]
GO

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.sysobjects WHERE id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[QRTZ_LOCKS]') AND OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'ISUSERTABLE') = 1)
DROP TABLE [dbo].[QRTZ_LOCKS]
GO

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.sysobjects WHERE id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[QRTZ_JOB_DETAILS]') AND OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'ISUSERTABLE') = 1)
DROP TABLE [dbo].[QRTZ_JOB_DETAILS]
GO

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.sysobjects WHERE id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[QRTZ_SIMPLE_TRIGGERS]') AND OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'ISUSERTABLE') = 1)
DROP TABLE [dbo].[QRTZ_SIMPLE_TRIGGERS]
GO

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.sysobjects WHERE id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[QRTZ_SIMPROP_TRIGGERS]') AND OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'ISUSERTABLE') = 1)
DROP TABLE [dbo].[QRTZ_SIMPROP_TRIGGERS]
GO

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.sysobjects WHERE id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[QRTZ_TRIGGERS]') AND OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'ISUSERTABLE') = 1)
DROP TABLE [dbo].[QRTZ_TRIGGERS]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[QRTZ_CALENDARS] (
  [SCHED_NAME] [VARCHAR] (120)  NOT NULL ,
  [CALENDAR_NAME] [VARCHAR] (200)  NOT NULL ,
  [CALENDAR] [VARBINARY] (max) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[QRTZ_CRON_TRIGGERS] (
  [SCHED_NAME] [VARCHAR] (120)  NOT NULL ,
  [TRIGGER_NAME] [VARCHAR] (200)  NOT NULL ,
  [TRIGGER_GROUP] [VARCHAR] (200)  NOT NULL ,
  [CRON_EXPRESSION] [VARCHAR] (120)  NOT NULL ,
  [TIME_ZONE_ID] [VARCHAR] (80) 
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[QRTZ_FIRED_TRIGGERS] (
  [SCHED_NAME] [VARCHAR] (120)  NOT NULL ,
  [ENTRY_ID] [VARCHAR] (95)  NOT NULL ,
  [TRIGGER_NAME] [VARCHAR] (200)  NOT NULL ,
  [TRIGGER_GROUP] [VARCHAR] (200)  NOT NULL ,
  [INSTANCE_NAME] [VARCHAR] (200)  NOT NULL ,
  [FIRED_TIME] [BIGINT] NOT NULL ,
  [SCHED_TIME] [BIGINT] NOT NULL ,
  [PRIORITY] [INTEGER] NOT NULL ,
  [STATE] [VARCHAR] (16)  NOT NULL,
  [JOB_NAME] [VARCHAR] (200)  NULL ,
  [JOB_GROUP] [VARCHAR] (200)  NULL ,
  [IS_NONCONCURRENT] [VARCHAR] (1)  NULL ,
  [REQUESTS_RECOVERY] [VARCHAR] (1)  NULL 
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[QRTZ_PAUSED_TRIGGER_GRPS] (
  [SCHED_NAME] [VARCHAR] (120)  NOT NULL ,
  [TRIGGER_GROUP] [VARCHAR] (200)  NOT NULL 
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[QRTZ_SCHEDULER_STATE] (
  [SCHED_NAME] [VARCHAR] (120)  NOT NULL ,
  [INSTANCE_NAME] [VARCHAR] (200)  NOT NULL ,
  [LAST_CHECKIN_TIME] [BIGINT] NOT NULL ,
  [CHECKIN_INTERVAL] [BIGINT] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[QRTZ_LOCKS] (
  [SCHED_NAME] [VARCHAR] (120)  NOT NULL ,
  [LOCK_NAME] [VARCHAR] (40)  NOT NULL 
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[QRTZ_JOB_DETAILS] (
  [SCHED_NAME] [VARCHAR] (120)  NOT NULL ,
  [JOB_NAME] [VARCHAR] (200)  NOT NULL ,
  [JOB_GROUP] [VARCHAR] (200)  NOT NULL ,
  [DESCRIPTION] [VARCHAR] (250) NULL ,
  [JOB_CLASS_NAME] [VARCHAR] (250)  NOT NULL ,
  [IS_DURABLE] [VARCHAR] (1)  NOT NULL ,
  [IS_NONCONCURRENT] [VARCHAR] (1)  NOT NULL ,
  [IS_UPDATE_DATA] [VARCHAR] (1)  NOT NULL ,
  [REQUESTS_RECOVERY] [VARCHAR] (1)  NOT NULL ,
  [JOB_DATA] [VARBINARY] (max) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[QRTZ_SIMPLE_TRIGGERS] (
  [SCHED_NAME] [VARCHAR] (120)  NOT NULL ,
  [TRIGGER_NAME] [VARCHAR] (200)  NOT NULL ,
  [TRIGGER_GROUP] [VARCHAR] (200)  NOT NULL ,
  [REPEAT_COUNT] [BIGINT] NOT NULL ,
  [REPEAT_INTERVAL] [BIGINT] NOT NULL ,
  [TIMES_TRIGGERED] [BIGINT] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[QRTZ_SIMPROP_TRIGGERS] (
  [SCHED_NAME] [VARCHAR] (120)  NOT NULL ,
  [TRIGGER_NAME] [VARCHAR] (200)  NOT NULL ,
  [TRIGGER_GROUP] [VARCHAR] (200)  NOT NULL ,
  [STR_PROP_1] [VARCHAR] (512) NULL,
  [STR_PROP_2] [VARCHAR] (512) NULL,
  [STR_PROP_3] [VARCHAR] (512) NULL,
  [INT_PROP_1] [INT] NULL,
  [INT_PROP_2] [INT] NULL,
  [LONG_PROP_1] [BIGINT] NULL,
  [LONG_PROP_2] [BIGINT] NULL,
  [DEC_PROP_1] [NUMERIC] (13,4) NULL,
  [DEC_PROP_2] [NUMERIC] (13,4) NULL,
  [BOOL_PROP_1] [VARCHAR] (1) NULL,
  [BOOL_PROP_2] [VARCHAR] (1) NULL,
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[QRTZ_BLOB_TRIGGERS] (
  [SCHED_NAME] [VARCHAR] (120)  NOT NULL ,
  [TRIGGER_NAME] [VARCHAR] (200)  NOT NULL ,
  [TRIGGER_GROUP] [VARCHAR] (200)  NOT NULL ,
  [BLOB_DATA] [VARBINARY] (max) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[QRTZ_TRIGGERS] (
  [SCHED_NAME] [VARCHAR] (120)  NOT NULL ,
  [TRIGGER_NAME] [VARCHAR] (200)  NOT NULL ,
  [TRIGGER_GROUP] [VARCHAR] (200)  NOT NULL ,
  [JOB_NAME] [VARCHAR] (200)  NOT NULL ,
  [JOB_GROUP] [VARCHAR] (200)  NOT NULL ,
  [DESCRIPTION] [VARCHAR] (250) NULL ,
  [NEXT_FIRE_TIME] [BIGINT] NULL ,
  [PREV_FIRE_TIME] [BIGINT] NULL ,
  [PRIORITY] [INTEGER] NULL ,
  [TRIGGER_STATE] [VARCHAR] (16)  NOT NULL ,
  [TRIGGER_TYPE] [VARCHAR] (8)  NOT NULL ,
  [START_TIME] [BIGINT] NOT NULL ,
  [END_TIME] [BIGINT] NULL ,
  [CALENDAR_NAME] [VARCHAR] (200)  NULL ,
  [MISFIRE_INSTR] [SMALLINT] NULL ,
  [JOB_DATA] [VARBINARY] (max) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[QRTZ_CALENDARS] WITH NOCHECK ADD
  CONSTRAINT [PK_QRTZ_CALENDARS] PRIMARY KEY  CLUSTERED
  (
    [SCHED_NAME],
    [CALENDAR_NAME]
  )  ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[QRTZ_CRON_TRIGGERS] WITH NOCHECK ADD
  CONSTRAINT [PK_QRTZ_CRON_TRIGGERS] PRIMARY KEY  CLUSTERED
  (
    [SCHED_NAME],
    [TRIGGER_NAME],
    [TRIGGER_GROUP]
  )  ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[QRTZ_FIRED_TRIGGERS] WITH NOCHECK ADD
  CONSTRAINT [PK_QRTZ_FIRED_TRIGGERS] PRIMARY KEY  CLUSTERED
  (
    [SCHED_NAME],
    [ENTRY_ID]
  )  ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[QRTZ_PAUSED_TRIGGER_GRPS] WITH NOCHECK ADD
  CONSTRAINT [PK_QRTZ_PAUSED_TRIGGER_GRPS] PRIMARY KEY  CLUSTERED
  (
    [SCHED_NAME],
    [TRIGGER_GROUP]
  )  ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[QRTZ_SCHEDULER_STATE] WITH NOCHECK ADD
  CONSTRAINT [PK_QRTZ_SCHEDULER_STATE] PRIMARY KEY  CLUSTERED
  (
    [SCHED_NAME],
    [INSTANCE_NAME]
  )  ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[QRTZ_LOCKS] WITH NOCHECK ADD
  CONSTRAINT [PK_QRTZ_LOCKS] PRIMARY KEY  CLUSTERED
  (
    [SCHED_NAME],
    [LOCK_NAME]
  )  ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[QRTZ_JOB_DETAILS] WITH NOCHECK ADD
  CONSTRAINT [PK_QRTZ_JOB_DETAILS] PRIMARY KEY  CLUSTERED
  (
    [SCHED_NAME],
    [JOB_NAME],
    [JOB_GROUP]
  )  ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[QRTZ_SIMPLE_TRIGGERS] WITH NOCHECK ADD
  CONSTRAINT [PK_QRTZ_SIMPLE_TRIGGERS] PRIMARY KEY  CLUSTERED
  (
    [SCHED_NAME],
    [TRIGGER_NAME],
    [TRIGGER_GROUP]
  )  ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[QRTZ_SIMPROP_TRIGGERS] WITH NOCHECK ADD
  CONSTRAINT [PK_QRTZ_SIMPROP_TRIGGERS] PRIMARY KEY  CLUSTERED
  (
    [SCHED_NAME],
    [TRIGGER_NAME],
    [TRIGGER_GROUP]
  )  ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[QRTZ_TRIGGERS] WITH NOCHECK ADD
  CONSTRAINT [PK_QRTZ_TRIGGERS] PRIMARY KEY  CLUSTERED
  (
    [SCHED_NAME],
    [TRIGGER_NAME],
    [TRIGGER_GROUP]
  )  ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[QRTZ_CRON_TRIGGERS] ADD
  CONSTRAINT [FK_QRTZ_CRON_TRIGGERS_QRTZ_TRIGGERS] FOREIGN KEY
  (
    [SCHED_NAME],
    [TRIGGER_NAME],
    [TRIGGER_GROUP]
  ) REFERENCES [dbo].[QRTZ_TRIGGERS] (
    [SCHED_NAME],
    [TRIGGER_NAME],
    [TRIGGER_GROUP]
  ) ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[QRTZ_SIMPLE_TRIGGERS] ADD
  CONSTRAINT [FK_QRTZ_SIMPLE_TRIGGERS_QRTZ_TRIGGERS] FOREIGN KEY
  (
    [SCHED_NAME],
    [TRIGGER_NAME],
    [TRIGGER_GROUP]
  ) REFERENCES [dbo].[QRTZ_TRIGGERS] (
    [SCHED_NAME],
    [TRIGGER_NAME],
    [TRIGGER_GROUP]
  ) ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[QRTZ_SIMPROP_TRIGGERS] ADD
  CONSTRAINT [FK_QRTZ_SIMPROP_TRIGGERS_QRTZ_TRIGGERS] FOREIGN KEY
  (
    [SCHED_NAME],
    [TRIGGER_NAME],
    [TRIGGER_GROUP]
  ) REFERENCES [dbo].[QRTZ_TRIGGERS] (
    [SCHED_NAME],
    [TRIGGER_NAME],
    [TRIGGER_GROUP]
  ) ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[QRTZ_BLOB_TRIGGERS] ADD
  CONSTRAINT [FK_QRTZ_BLOB_TRIGGERS_QRTZ_TRIGGERS] FOREIGN KEY
  (
    [SCHED_NAME],
    [TRIGGER_NAME],
    [TRIGGER_GROUP]
  ) REFERENCES [dbo].[QRTZ_TRIGGERS] (
    [SCHED_NAME],
    [TRIGGER_NAME],
    [TRIGGER_GROUP]
  ) ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[QRTZ_TRIGGERS] ADD
  CONSTRAINT [FK_QRTZ_TRIGGERS_QRTZ_JOB_DETAILS] FOREIGN KEY
  (
    [SCHED_NAME],
    [JOB_NAME],
    [JOB_GROUP]
  ) REFERENCES [dbo].[QRTZ_JOB_DETAILS] (
    [SCHED_NAME],
    [JOB_NAME],
    [JOB_GROUP]
  )
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_QRTZ_CRON_TRIGGERS_QRTZ_TRIGGERS] ON [dbo].[QRTZ_CRON_TRIGGERS]
  (
    [SCHED_NAME] ASC,
    [TRIGGER_NAME] ASC,
    [TRIGGER_GROUP] ASC
  ) WITH (
    PAD_INDEX  = OFF,
    STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF,
    SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF,
    IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,
    DROP_EXISTING = OFF,
    ONLINE = OFF,
    ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON,
    ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON
  ) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_QRTZ_SIMPLE_TRIGGERS_QRTZ_TRIGGERS] ON [dbo].[QRTZ_SIMPLE_TRIGGERS]
  (
    [SCHED_NAME] ASC,
    [TRIGGER_NAME] ASC,
    [TRIGGER_GROUP] ASC
  ) WITH (
    PAD_INDEX  = OFF,
    STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF,
    SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF,
    IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,
    DROP_EXISTING = OFF,
    ONLINE = OFF,
    ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON,
    ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON
  ) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_QRTZ_SIMPROP_TRIGGERS_QRTZ_TRIGGERS] ON [dbo].[QRTZ_SIMPROP_TRIGGERS]
  (
    [SCHED_NAME] ASC,
    [TRIGGER_NAME] ASC,
    [TRIGGER_GROUP] ASC
  ) WITH (
    PAD_INDEX  = OFF,
    STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF,
    SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF,
    IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,
    DROP_EXISTING = OFF,
    ONLINE = OFF,
    ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON,
    ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON
  ) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_QRTZ_TRIGGERS_QRTZ_JOB_DETAILS] ON [dbo].[QRTZ_TRIGGERS]
  (
    [SCHED_NAME] ASC,
    [TRIGGER_NAME] ASC,
    [TRIGGER_GROUP] ASC
  ) WITH (
    PAD_INDEX  = OFF,
    STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF,
    SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF,
    IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,
    DROP_EXISTING = OFF,
    ONLINE = OFF,
    ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON,
    ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON
  ) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

I used the code from this tutorial

https://stackabuse.com/guide-to-quartz-with-spring-boot-job-scheduling-and-automation/

I also tried adding
`org.quartz.jobStore.selectWithLockSQL=SELECT * FROM {0}LOCKS UPDLOCK WHERE LOCK_NAME = ?`
which didn't change anything.

Comment: _"quartz_tables_h2.sql"_ is for H2, not SQL server. You need to use the right script for SQL Server.

Comment: Also, you need to use the `MSSQLDelegate` instead of `StdJDBCDelegate`.

Comment: Which sql script should I use instead?

Comment: `table_sqlServer.sql`, which is included in the `src/org/quartz/impl/jdbcjobstore` of the distribution, and in the `org/quartz/impl/jdbcjobstore` of the library JAR.

Comment: Still same error. I added the new SQL script to the question.

Comment: Have you also switched to using the `MSSQLDelegate` instead of `StdJDBCDelegate`?

Comment: Still `FOR UPDATE clause allowed only for DECLARE CURSOR` after changing to `MSSQLDelegate`

Comment: Fixed it by adding `SelectMethod=cursor;` to the end of my datasource url

Comment: Good to hear. I recommend you post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it by adding `SelectMethod=cursor;` to the end of my datasource url

```
server.port=8080

spring.sql.init.schema-locations=classpath:db/quartz_tables_h2.sql
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://123.45.6.789;databaseName=myDB;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true;SelectMethod=cursor
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=debug

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
```